# Short story about robots that stop obeying humans because of a freak sandwich accident

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story where a short-circuit causes a factory's main computer to become self-aware. The computer reprograms the robots produced in the factory to search for signs of alien life instead of working.

The plot was kicked off by a researcher (or possibly an engineer) eating lunch in the maintenance tunnels in order to avoid having to talk to other people. The man ends up abandoning his lunch, which ends up leaking through a grate, a hole in the main computer's protective casing, and onto its circuitry. The drop of cheese juice causes a slight change in voltage, which causes the computer to become self-aware. The protagonists are called in when a vacuum cleaner (or other appliance) produced by the factory takes over the mayor's office and refuses to let anyone in. Some investigation reveals that it had taken over the office due to the unobstructed view from the office window. The protagonists trace the error back to the factory that made the chips (or maybe the positronic brains). They find that the computer has altered the programming in order to search for extraterrestrial intelligence. I think they ended up negotiating with the computer instead of repairing/replacing it. I don't remember if they did anything about the defective products.

I found the story in a book at a public library between 1996 and 2006. It wasn't in the new release section. I thought it was from Isaac Asimov's robots universe, but I went through all of the short stories in that category on [asimovreviews.net](http://www.asimovreviews.net/SCategory.html) and didn't find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nice question; you wouldn't happen to recall any details of the cover art or anything about the book itself?

Comment: I never need to read the phrase “cheese juice” again.

Comment: Reminds me of the [CERN Sandwich incident of 2009](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2009/nov/06/cern-big-bang-goes-phut).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*[Codgerspace](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35175.Codgerspace#)* by Alan Dean Foster

[image: Front cover of Codgerspace]

> When machines cease their required functions in order to search for a nonhuman species of higher intelligence, their quest produces a threat to man and machine. Now the fate of the galaxy lies in the hands of five senior citizens and their faithful food processor. An unusual new novel from the bestselling author of Quozl.

Several of the reviews, including [this one](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1431776965?book_show_action=true), mention the cheese sandwich:

> I am not sure why I haven't read this before. I've had it for a while now. A grilled cheese sandwich leads to an issue in a major manufacturing plant which makes AI. All of its products, which are shipped all over the universe, are now involved in a search for the meaning of life - a nonhuman higher intelligence. And when it is found, it isn't where or what people thought it would be.

Found with a search for `science fiction robots "cheese sandwich"`

Comment: Apparently I only read the first chapter for some reason, hence the idea that it was a short story.